# Cocos 2d tilemap. Sprite at 0,0 is partially off the map?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a tiledmap based app and I'm working on getting a sprite to move around on it. However I noticed something as I was working on this. If I run the following code:

```
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
playerSprite.position = ccp(x,y);
```

Then my player is actually off the map:

[image: Player off map]

Should I instead be making up for this by positioning my character at:

```
playerSprite.position = ccp(x + playerSprite.boundingBox.size.width / 2,  y + playerSprite.boundingBox.size.height / 2)
```

Or am I doing something wrong with my map configuration? Should the tile not extend to the full 0,0?

My map is initialized as follows:

```
// Setup our map
map = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile: @"Map.tmx"];
NSAssert(nil != map, @"Map is nil");

[self addChild: map z: -1];
```

And the player is initialized width:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile: @"SpriteTest.plist"];
CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"SpriteTest.png"];
[self addChild: spriteSheet];

self.playerSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName: @"cyanWalkHorizontal1.png"];
[spriteSheet addChild: self.playerSprite];
self.playerSprite.position = ccp(0,0);
```

So, overall i'm just wondering if im doing the initialization wrong, of it I should be accounting for the sprites width/height when positioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From cocos2d documentation:](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.0.0/interface_c_c_node.html#ac24fc742eb11ee96207052639224434c)

> anchorPoint is the point around which all transformations and
>   positioning manipulations take place. It's like a pin in the node
>   where it is "attached" to its parent. The anchorPoint is normalized,
>   like a percentage. (0,0) means the bottom-left corner and (1,1) means
>   the top-right corner. But you can use values higher than (1,1) and
>   lower than (0,0) too. The default anchorPoint is (0,0). It starts in
>   the bottom-left corner. CCSprite and other subclasses have a different
>   default anchorPoint.

CCSprite's default anchor point is (0.5, 0.5) - in the center of the sprite.

Comment: Thats for pointing that out to me. I'm a bit confused though.. if the default anchorPoint for a CCSprite is 0.5,0.5 (and I confimed that this was what my playerSprite's anchorPoint was), then shouldn't it line up with the map properly without me needing to add `playerSprite.boundingBox.size.width / 2` to the x position?

Comment: No. When you set position for the node, it's its anchor point which will be pinned to the point with these coordinates in node's parent. So when you have sprite with anchor point in its center and set its position to (0, 0), then its center will be at (0, 0) point of its's parent. And node's origin is always in bottom  left corner, regardless of anchor point.

Answer (score 0):

In game development, sprite [registration points](http://askville.amazon.com/Flash-registration-points/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=6721785) can vary. In this case, it seems that the registration point is set to the center of the sprite, so you should compensate by adding/removing half the width and height.